# Populate textbox with selected items from database

Tags: c#

```
    private void fillProduct() {

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STATION21\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=true");
    conn.Open();

    string query = "Select prodID from product";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
        cmbPCode.DataSource = dt;
        cmbPCode.DisplayMember = "prodID";
        cmbPCode.ValueMember = "prodID";
    }


    private void cmbPCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STATION21\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=true");
        con.Open();

        string query = "Select * from product where prodID = '"+cmbPCode.Text+"'".ToString();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read()) {
            tbdc.Text = dr["prodDescription"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

i am having trouble with getting my items from the database according to the selected index i get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int

can someone please help me how to convert SqlDataReader to String. because i notice that when i retrieve a column with varchar/string datatype i am not having this kind error but if i retrieve a column with int datatype i get this error.

Comment: On which line you get this error? And why you are using `.ToString()` at the end your `query` ? That's seems pointless.

Comment: i am having error with my dr.Read(); i just put .ToString() and try if it will solve my problem but actually it doesnt i still get this error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int

Comment: then i try to change the item that i retrieve with prodName and i notice that it works i think maybe because the datatype of my prodName is varchar can you please help me how to convert int to string so that i will no longer get this error

Answer (score 0):

Replace This:

```
string query = "Select * from product where prodID = '"+cmbPCode.Text+
                                                                 "'".ToString();
```

With This:

```
string query = "Select * from product where prodID = "+cmbPCode.Text;
```

**Suggestion:** Your query is open to SQL Injection i would suggest you to use parameterised queries to avoid them.

Using Parameterised Queries:

```
 string query = "Select * from product where prodID = @ID";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",cmbPCode.Text);
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why OP get's that error.

Comment: i still get this error
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

Comment: but if i try to change retrieve records with the varchar data type i dont get this error but if i try to retrieve records with int data type i get this error i usually get this error at my dr.Read();